# Get Ip from Steam Game Server?

Tags: c#, discord, steam, steam-web-api

Is there a way to determine the Ip of a specific game server via Steam's WEB API? I have already asked Steam, they just said that the support will not help me. The reason for my question is that I am writing a Discord Bot for friends to check the server status of the server, but it has a dynamic Ip, now we give the bot always the current Ip, but if possible he should do it himself.

Comment: I don't know about the Steam API, but have you looked into setting up a dynamic DNS on your server? That way it would always be reachable under the same address and the bot could just use that to check the server's status.

Comment: I have already mentioned this possibility to my friends! The gameserver runs on the home pc of the friends! But yes DynDns would be an option. According to what my friends say.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the Steam game server IP adress.

This [video](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1024933/Denial-of-Service) answers why Steam will not give you their server IP adresses:

- a classic IP address will be subject to DDOS attacks
- all their servers a are behind server gateway which assign dynamic IPs
- No public service exists to get the dynamic IP because that would give DDos attackers an automated way to attack the gateway